# Parenting Armatures Causes Animation to Break

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I have made an animated conveyor belt. Now, I want to parent all the objects to a single empty, allowing me to translate and rotate the object and armature together.

If I do not rotate or translate the new empty, then everything works fine.

However, if the parent empty rotates, the pieces of the track warp out of shape.

I am still trying to understand why this is happening. Can anyone please illuminate what I have done wrong?

**Before Rotation**

[image: Before Rotation]

**After Rotation**
[image: After Rotation]

**Project File**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. delete your empty
2. add a new empty

[image]

3. select all conveyor_roller* (3 objects) and the path curve (shift-select)
4. at last shift-select the empty
5. press ctrl-p -> object

result:

[image]